# Distribution of Code with Visual Studio Express Products

Tags: visual-studio-2008, licensing

I installed Visual Studio (Web Developer in this case) Express Edition and was reading through the EULA. One thing that did not jump out at me was what I was allowed to use the software for (private, commercial, etc).

Does anyone know if you are allowed to sell/distribute the code you create in these Express editions? I know they are geared toward the hobbyist and other software licenses, like the Student and Teacher editions of Office, do not allow commercial use for the software.

I'd like to eventually start giving out code either via OSS licenses like BSD or GPL and even maybe sell some code but not sure I can do that with the Express Editions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Yes](http://www.microsoft.com/express/support/faq/), you can use the Express Editions for commercial use.

Comment: It's answer number 7 in the FAQ: http://www.microsoft.com/express/support/faq/

Comment: These links are broken now, just FYI.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot create an executable and then run it on another computer unless that computer has Visual Studio Express installed on it. Don't believe any comments to the contrary. I have tried all the suggestions on how to do this and they don't work.

Comment: You can, they might have to separately install the runtime first though...