# Can you redistribute msvcrtxx.dll from an app build using visual studio express?

Tags: visual-c++, licensing, redistributable, msvcr90.dll, visual-c++-runtime

When you download visual C++ 2008 express edition, this file exists:

```
./Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/VC/redist/x86/Microsoft.VC90.CRT/msvcr90.dll
```

In the file redist.txt it says

> The following list is a list of files available with Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 for redistribution under the Visual Studio 2008 license.  If the Microsoft software you have licensed is not Visual Studio 2008, only the files that are installed by the Microsoft software may be redistributed under such license.

and includes the above msvcr90.dll

So my question is, does this license allow you to distribute msvcr90.dll from express or not? What does "only the files that are installed by the Microsoft software" mean?  Any help? (specifically, is it not allowed to distribute a version of msvcr90.dll with an app built by mingw/gcc).

Comment: you can probably get away with it, in the least, by distributing your app along with one compiled by a real version of MSVC, and using that one's msvcr90.dll

Comment: This appears related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179596/distribution-of-code-with-visual-studio-express-products

Comment: also related is that VC express 2010 has a checkbox option to install "debug redistributables" whatever that's worth.

Comment: Also if you install the Microsoft SDK you also get this dir: G:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Redist FWIW

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing and legal issues, not programming or software development. See [[here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846)] for details, and the [[help/on-topic]] for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current thought is that you can probably get away with "running" MS's official msvc redistributable exe. as part of your install process (or possibly download it separately, if you detect they do not have it installed)

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/9214753/32453